AWS: Deny policy for detaching a specific policy from a specific resource
I am trying structure an AWS IAM policy that denies a specific role and a specific managed policy from being detached from each other.
Let's say there's a role "developer" with the permissions "iam:AttachRolePolicy" and "iam:DetachRolePolicy" attached to it via a custom-managed policy. So the role has permission to attach/detach other role policies to/from itself and other resources (I know the example is a bit recursive, but please stay with me).
I would like to "Deny" the "developer" role from accidentally detaching the above mentioned two policies from itself. So the "developer" role should not accidentally detach its permissions to add / remove policies to itself.
Now such a scenario requires a "Deny" policy - but my problem is that it relates to multiple resources - a role (developer) and two policies (Attach/Detach). To clarify, I don't want to stop the role from detaching other policies from any resource and I don't want to stop the role from attaching new policies to any resource. I just want to deny it from detaching these 2 specific roles from the "developer" role.
How would you do such a thing?

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_controlling.html#access_controlling-policies . You can write a Deny policy specifying the action of detaching a policy from the role in question and in the condition have the two blocked policy arns.

Couldn't you just grant them permission to attach/detach any policy, as long as it isn't that particular policy? This would use NotResource to specify every other policy. It also avoids use of a Deny policy (which is never easy to use).
